# Does valueOf always override toString in javascript?

Tags: javascript, tostring

Is there any expression where by an object's toString method is **implicitly** called overriding its valueOf method?

In the examples below, valueOf is always called implicitly (overriding toString).

```
"4" + {
    toString: function () {
        return "4";
    },
    valueOf: function () {
        return 6;
    }
};    // => "46", was expecting "44"

4 + {
    toString: function () {
        return "6";
    },
    valueOf: function () {
        return 4;
    }
};    // => 8

4 + {
    toString: function () {
        return 6;
    },
    valueOf: function() {
        return "4";
    }
};    // => "44"
```

i.e.:

Can we write an expression where by toString is implicitly called over valueOf (i.e without explicitly calling toString)?

Comment: i checked that prior, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: You could do `var ob = {
    toString: function () {
        return "4";
    },
    valueOf: function () {
        return 6;
    }
}; 


console.log( "4" + String(ob));`

Comment: Wrapping it with String object is basically calling toString explicitly. My question was if it can be done implicitly, by the js engine.

Comment: That wasn't your question. You asked is there an expression.... without explicitly calling toString()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The + operator on Date objects uses toString not valueOf. Also if valueOf returns a non-primitive value then the toString method is called next. (JavaScript - The definitive guide, section 3.14) Using your example:

```
var result = "4" + {
    toString: function () {
        return "4";
    },
    valueOf: function () {
        return this; // returning an object, not a primitive
    }
};
```

Result is now 44.

Comment: Still, `valueOf` is called first here and would be featured if it did return a primitive value. I wouldn't say `toString` is not "overridden" by it.

Comment: I agree, and I hope that my wording in the answer reflects that. But I think this is a use-case that's important to point out because eventually the effect is "toString was returned not valueOf".

Comment: I think a usecase where `valueOf` does not return a primitive is hardly useful. You might as well (better?) simply *omit* the `valueOf` method then. Agreed, it might be helpful when the method is shared across objects (and returns different values) but not on an object literal like in your example :-)

Comment: If we are going into the technicality: all objects have valueOf method inherited from Object and the default one returns the object itself (just like my example does). So technically speaking if you don't provide a valueOf method on your object what happens is that toString will be used over valueOf :) I use the word "used" not "called" because valueOf is also called before toString.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any expression where by an object's toString method is implicitly called overriding its valueOf method?

Yes, that does happen whenever the abstract [`ToString` operation](http://es5.github.io/#x9.8) is applied on an object, using the [`DefaultValue` procedure](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) with `.toString()` before `.valueOf()`.

However, in your examples you have only used the [addition operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1) which is like an exception from the standard behaviour. Since it does not only concatenate strings, but also sums numbers, it always uses `valueOf` on both operands before checking whether they're strings. See the note 1:

> No hint is provided in the calls to ToPrimitive in steps 5
>   and 6. All native ECMAScript objects except Date objects handle the
>   absence of a hint as if the hint Number were given; Date objects
>   handle the absence of a hint as if the hint String were given. Host
>   objects may handle the absence of a hint in some other manner.

So which operations do implicitly use the `ToString` instead of a hint-less `ToPrimitive`? Here are a few examples:

- Everything about property names: The `in` operator, bracket notation, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`, `Object.defineProperty`, `hasOwnProperty`, …
- Functions expecting strings as arguments: `parseInt`, `parseFloat`, `encodeURI[Component]`, `decodeURI[Component]`, `[un]escape`, `Array::join`, `String::[last]indexOf`, `RegExp::exec`
- The `Function` constructor
- The `Array::sort` algorithm's default compare function
- The `String` constructor and String methods when casting the `this` object to a string
- The `RegExp` constructor
- The `Error` constructors
- Lots of other functions not specified by EcmaScript but in the DOM or somewhere else, like `alert`, `XMlHTTPRequest::open`, `querySelector`, …

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there any expression*

Yes. Here's an example that will use `toString`:

```
alert({
    toString: function () {
        return "4";
    },
    valueOf: function () {
        return 6;
    }
});  // alerts "4"
```

Comment: Could you explain why? (I'm curious)

Comment: ok, but can you write an expression where by toString is implicitly called over valueOf (i.e without an explicit call to toString).

Comment: @RUJordan it probably has to do with that `alert` expects as a parameter (a string to be displayed). It's not an expression really, it's an object literal being passed as a parameter to a function expecting a string.