# Can valueOf() / toString() be overriden and inherited?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

So I'm doing personal research, and trying to learn more about JavaScript inheritance etc. I've stumbled upon a question. Examine the code.

```
var x = function() {}, y = 10;
x.valueOf = function() {
  return y + 10;   
}
x.prototype.valueOf = function() {
   return y + 5; 
}
var z = new x();
console.log(z, x); // x {valueOf: function} 20 
x.prototype.valueOf = x.valueOf;
var k = new x();
console.log(k, x); //x {valueOf: function} 20  the same!
```

I am trying to make braceless method calls. I understand valueOf can be used for this, but same is with `toString`. But, with toString I shouldn't be able having result of `console.log(z, x)` as 20 for `x`.

Comment: yes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

Comment: and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: so ,when i override valueOf, i can no longer call the function without round brackets?

Comment: You can, you will get back your override-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> x.prototype.valueOf = x.valueOf;
> var k = new x();
> console.log(k, x); //x {valueOf: function} 20  the same!
> ```

Sure, why not? `k` now inherits a different `valueOf` function than the one of `z` that was logged before, but `x.valueOf` didn't change.

It's quite odd anyway that `console.log` calls own `.valueOf()` methods - notice that **`console.log` is non-standard** and not a reliable tool to prove anything. Better:

```
function x() {}
x.valueOf = function() { return 20; };
x.prototype.valueOf = function() { return 15; };
var z = new x();
z.valueOf(); // 15
x.valueOf(); // 20
x.prototype.valueOf = x.valueOf;
var k = new x();
k.valueOf(); // 20
x.valueOf(); // 20
```

---

> Trying to make braceless method calls.

You might want to have a look at getters/setters.

> I understand valueOf can be used for this, but same is with toString

Yes, `valueOf` and `toString` are automatically called when an object is cast to a primitive value - e.g. when using mathematical operators on it or doing concatenation with a string. The rules when exactly `toValue` and when `toString` is called are difficult; [more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20893585/1048572).

Example:

```
z+x; // 35
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think console.log does a toString. But when you try it with alert() you will see it works:

```
x=function(val){this.val=val;};
y=new x(20)
x.prototype.toString=function(){return "my value is: " + this.val;};
alert(y)
```

And for valueOf:

```
x.prototype.valueOf=function(){return this.val + 10;};
alert(y+5)
```